# How do I change the Chrome installation folder on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

I am trying to run the selenium server and in the instructions it is said that the server assumes that Chrome is located at  `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`.

1. How do I check that it is actually located there? Because when I go to my application folder, I see that my Chrome is located at `/Applications/Google Chrome.app`
2. How do I move it to that location (`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`)?

The problem is that when I am running the selenium test now, it opens Firefox instead of Chrome. So figure the problem is in the above path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So figure the problem is in the above path

No. *Google Chrome.app* is the application package for Google Chrome. It contains one executable file, which is under *Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome*.

This file is really opened by OS X when you start Google Chrome.

[image]

If Firefox is opened automatically, I presume it's set as the system wide default browser. Just go to Google Chrome's preferences and set it as the default browser. Or, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317055/how-to-run-google-chrome-with-selenium-rc) suggests, to specifiy `googlechrome` from Selenium.

You really seem to be having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).