# Where is Google Chrome located on a Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Where is Google Chrome located on a Mac?

The first few Google results didn't help. Maybe this will be the new best Google result.

Comment: It's worth noting that Macs have always let you put apps wherever you want, and move them at will as easy as moving any other file. Apps (or installers or updaters) that hard-code paths are considered sub-par. That said, most people follow the convention of keeping all their apps in /Applications.

Comment: I found it in `Applications/`, but needed to go to the root of the drive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to "[chrome install location osx](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20install%20location%20osx)", which leads to [How do I change the Chrome installation folder on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/371083/how-do-i-change-the-chrome-installation-folder-on-a-mac), it is with the rest of the applications in the usual spot at `/Applications/Google Chrome.app`.

If it's not there, multiple techniques for locating it (or any application) can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95837/find-google-chrome-installation-directory-on-mac-using-terminal) (also via the search results above):

- In a terminal:

  ```
  find / -type d -name "*Chrome.app"
  ```
- In a terminal (answerer was using Mountain Lion):

  ```
  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep -i "google chrome"
  ```

I suppose you could also search your computer for "Google Chrome.app".

The related questions on the right side of this page also contain useful information. For example, [How do I uninstall Google Chrome *completely* from my Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/318186/how-do-i-uninstall-google-chrome-completely-from-my-mac?rq=1) shows where application settings are located.

Answer (score 26):

This also helps:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

Taken from:
[Start Google Chrome on Mac with command line switches](https://superuser.com/questions/157484/start-google-chrome-on-mac-with-command-line-switches)

Comment: this worked!!!!!

Comment: binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Answer (score 2):

I found `chrome://version` very helpful. Here is my output

```
Arc 118.0.5993.117 (Official Build) (x86_64) 
Revision    fdb2355de50518294b88ace7bc851820dc38aa82-refs/branch-heads/5993@{#1402}
OS  macOS Version 12.6 (Build 21G115)
JavaScript  V8 11.8.172.16
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /Applications/Arc.app/Contents/MacOS/Arc --flag-switches-begin --disable-quic --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU
Executable Path /Applications/Arc.app/Contents/MacOS/Arc
Profile Path    /Users/crazyones110/Library/Application Support/Arc/User Data/Default
Linker  lld
Variations Seed Type    Null
```

From which, you can get command-line options, executable path and so on.